# Problem adding elements to a Map

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following for loop:

```
for(FGM_Base__Benchmark__c bmrecords:[
    select id, Number_Completed__c, (
        select id, FGM_Base__Number_Update__c, Status_Grantee_Report__c
        from FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r
        )
    from FGM_Base__Benchmark__c
    where id =:benchmarkIdsSet]){

    masterBMSwithChildrenBUStobeClaculatedmap.put(bmrecords, bmrecords.FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r.FGM_Base__Number_Update__c);
}
```

The issue I am having is that I can not add the second element into the map. I get an error :

> a non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression:
>   FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r

I do understand the error but can not figure out how I can fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. My goal is really get a map of FGM_Base__Benchmark__c and FGM_Base__Number_Update__c, so that I can iterate over the map, and sum all of the FGM_Base__Number_Update__c per each FGM_Base__Benchmark__c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner query here will return a list of records and thus when you try to access a particular field on that list, you are getting the error. This query will return a list of `FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates`

```
select ... (select ... from FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r) from ...
```

If you want to access a particular field from `FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates`, you will need to first fetch the specific record and then get that field. A typical iteration on relationship queries will look like as:

```
for(FGM_Base__Benchmark__c bmrecords : 
        [select ... (select ... from FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r) from ...]) {
    ...
    List<FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates> childRecs = bmrecords.FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r;
    for(FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates c: childRecs ) {

        // this is how you can get the field here
        c.FGM_Base__Number_Update__c;
        ... do something ...
    }
}
```

It depends on what are you trying to add here, if you just want to add the list of the records returned for that particular parent record, you can simply use the following:

```
masterBMSwithChildrenBUStobeClaculatedmap.put(bmrecords, bmrecords.FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r);
```

---

Take a look at [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) for more details here.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to access child records by querying on the parent object i.e. by using inner query, there can be multiple child records i.e. there can be multiple `FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r` records. Hence, you won't be able to access the fields of child record using dot notation without using index.

Due to the above mentioned reason, below statement becomes invalid

```
masterBMSwithChildrenBUStobeClaculatedmap.put(bmrecords, bmrecords.FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r.FGM_Base__Number_Update__c);
```

If you want to get only the first record out of `FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r` list, you can use the index and then use dot notation to access that field.

```
masterBMSwithChildrenBUStobeClaculatedmap.put(bmrecords, bmrecords.FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r[0].FGM_Base__Number_Update__c);
```

But above statement, can lead to index out of bound exception or can give null pointer exception.

Other way to do is to change your map to `Map<FGM_Base__Benchmark__c, List<FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__c>>` and add the values to map using below statement and then you can use this map further to implement your logic.

```
masterBMSwithChildrenBUStobeClaculatedmap.put(bmrecords, bmrecords.FGM_Base__Benchmark_Updates__r);
```